# Reputation awarding when asker never selects the answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

There should be some reward in reputation to answers with 2 (suggestion) or more upvotes and the asker has not chosen the correct answer after a long time.

Maybe give more established users a way to say which answer is most suited and then once it hits a certain level, the question is then remotely answered by those votes. After a certain period of time.

It's somewhat annoying to answer someone's question so that I can gain privleges and it's the only answer and correct answer and the asker never awards upvotes or selected answer.

Comment: If you're here for the reputation, I suggest you go and write some production code instead.

Comment: No, I come on here to help people with their problems and when they don't even acknowledge my efforts its somewhat rude. reputation is just a means of showing that. I would settle for a comment saying that I helped them just as well...

Comment: Not to mention having a level of reputation does give you some leverage on questions for answers, aka bounty

Comment: Many posters find the accept button a long time after they first asked a question and work through their older questions. You'll probably randomly get accepts up to about a year or so after some answers - look at it as in investment in the future if it bothers you too much.

Comment: @awoodland I just recently got an Accept on a question from Sept '10, which was about when I was first active on the site. I voted to delete the already closed question... hehe (it was about books)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The community does select the correct answer, with upvotes.  An upvote is +10 rep, and an answer selected as "accepted" is +15, so upvotes are just as good.

The answer with the most upvotes can usually be looked at as "correct" even if the asker didn't mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Yep, that's the way it's supposed to work...no automated and potentially very game-able system needed here.

Comment: Is it ironic that this answer isn't accepted? ^_^

Answer (score 2):

What if none of the answers solve the asker's original problem?  Maybe they're good enough answers to earn upvotes, but they don't completely solve the problem.

Why should they be marked as accepted?

This could even be potentially misleading to future perusers of such questions.

The bottom line is that it's the asker's responsibility to select an answer as accepted, *if any of the answers are deserving of such selection*.  But often, the asker accepts a poor answer or doesn't accept a good answer.  Tough beans, but it's hard to legislate that.

Comment: I don't mean to have it marked as accepted. Just some acknowledgement or reward from the asker is all I'm talking about here. But I suppose if the question is good enough, there will be a bounty associated with it at some point. The main thing I'm driving at here is to give some incentive to answer a question posed by someone who just created an account to shamelessly ask a question on the site. They have no care in the world if anyone else learns from their question, they just want an answer. What then?

Comment: As I said, *that's that asker's responsiblity*, unless we decide to legislate it.  And I think any legislation is bound to fail.  And those people you mention -- they are typically blocked from posting on the site if they ask poor questions and are unable to improve. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system

Answer (score 1):

The upvotes you get come with +10 reputation, so you already get a reward. If the asker upvotes your answer, that works the same.

Since you already get rewarded for every upvote you receive I don't think additional reputation for getting  upvotes is necessary.